# How do you copy and Paste in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Every time I try to copy and paste a web url into PyCharm, I even tried Paste Simple, I see nothing. Is there any force that could potentially block out people who try to paste information in? I really have no clue what's going on.

Comment: Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V work for me. They even have [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/cutting-copying-and-pasting.html) showing that it should work.

Comment: or try Ctrl+Insert and Shift+Insert, or even mouse right click 'Copy' and 'Paste'?

Comment: You didn't even tell what platform and what version of pycharm are you using...

Comment: If plain Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V don't work your terminal may require that you also hold down the Shift key to do copy & paste.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using pycharm 4.0.4 on windows 8

Comment: PyCharm 5.0.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 also has never worked - only thing I can copy/paste to is a text editor, not a terminal window or browser. It's getting old, have to do a two-step copy/paste all the time - JetBrains...

Answer (score 21):

Most likely you installed the IdeaVim support when you first installed PyCharm. To un-install the plugin, go to:

> File --> Settings --> Plugins

and uncheck the IdeaVim entry.

You will need to restart PyCharm.  After I did this, I could easily copy and paste via CTRL + C/X/V from anywhere into PyCharm.

Comment: I don't have the option to uncheck IdeaVim. How do you do this?

Answer (score 14):

PyCharm version 4.04 does not allow me to paste text from a source (like a text editor, url, document) into a file open in PyCharm. I can cut and paste between two files open in PyCharm. Reverting back to PyCharm version 4.01 returned the expected paste operation for me.

Running PyCharm on windows 8

Answer (score 5):

```
SW VER :
PyCharm 2018.3.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-183.5153.39, built on January 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b26 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

- File → Setings → Editor → Vim Emulation:
- all the copy / paste / cat keywords (Ctrl C / V / X) are in "Vim" in Handler
  columns. Change it to "IDE".
- Apply → OK.

It will start working immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Similar here..  Windows 7, Pycharm community edition 4.5.4.  Can copy-paste from pycharm to outside apps.  But when doing reverse, there are inconsistent behaviors.

From notepad (or even this editor windows where I am typing this), I can copy to pycharm.  However, if I copy any other text (say, an article from wikipedia), I cannot paste in to pycharm. Clicking on paste does absolutely nothing.

So current solution:  Copy something ... paste to notepad. Then copy from notepad and paste to pycharm.

Comment: The windows notepad is a way to bypass "smart" filter in PyCharm !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like just a bug. I use 2016.1 and restart helps.

Comment: This doesn't provide any value add from other answers.

Answer (score 1):

IdeaVim plugin doesnot allow to to use shortcut keys properly as it has different configuration for shortcut keys. So **uninstalling IdeaVim** and then followed by **restarting PyCharm** works out well.

- To do the above :-
  File -> Settings -> Plugins -> (search for IdeaVim) **Uninstall** it or **disable** it
- It will ask for restart, so **restart PyCharm**

Comment: This looks exactly like the top answer by @Eric. A new answer should add new, or different, information.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, I fixed it after disabling antivirus safe search in the browser and restarted Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

When the copy/ paste shortcuts are failed, I found `Execute Selection in Console` (alt  + shift + E) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have just learned that using the python browser allows you to paste too the pi only (my experience). not from the desktop to pi. I assume it is because their are two different platforms running on the same screen. when i'm on full screen with the pi on my desktop, i can't (ALT Tab) to the desktop. But i can vice versa. hope this helps. i have only just started to learn pi and programming etc

Answer (score 0):

Go to "View"  then goto "quick switch scheme" then set you  "keymap" to "windows".

This worked for me.
I did not need to uninstall idealvim.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my issues of copy, paste, inserting after selection.

Go to [Tools] in pychar-menu-bar and uncheck on [Vim Emulator]