# I cannot copy and paste from PyCharm to other applications

Tags: pycharm

Firstly I have to mention that I don't have any vim plugins, which are most answers about.

I'm not using the Ctrl + C/V shortcut, the right-click fails to work as well.
The problem is:

- I can copy and paste within PyCharm.
- I can copy some text in other application and paste it in PyCharm.
- I cannot copy anything from PyCharm and paste it in other application. I can see that I have copied something in my clipboard (win10 has this), but it is empty.

I even tried to open PyCharm as administrator, but it still doesn't work.

I'm using win10 64bit OS, and PyCharm 2020.1.2 (community).
Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you copy and Paste in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144352/how-do-you-copy-and-paste-in-pycharm)

Comment: Unfortunately no... I don't have the IdeaVim plugin as I said. Maybe I have to install another version?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206835985--SOLVED-Ctrl-V-and-Ctrl-C-doesn-t-work-in-intellij-IDEA-14-0-2 look at the solution by Pat Moran

Comment: Thanks for finding this but it still doesn't work for me...I have even tried to install and uninstall IdeaVim and make sure that the encoding of the project is utf-8.

Comment: Fresh install of PyCharm? I don't have any other solutions. sorry

Comment: Thank you anyway. It seems that I have to reinstall it.